Saving subclassed model in Keras
I want to save my model for deployment and it sounds like it's not possible for subclassed model.
what do you recommend me to do?
batch = next(iter(val_ds))

idx_to_char = vectorizer.get_vocabulary()

display_cb = DisplayOutputs(batch, idx_to_char, target_start_token_idx=2, target_end_token_idx=3)

model = Transformer(num_hid=200,num_head=2,num_feed_forward=400,target_maxlen=max_target_len,num_layers_enc=4,num_layers_dec=1,num_classes=34,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1,)



learning_rate = CustomSchedule(init_lr=0.00001,lr_after_warmup=0.0001,final_lr=0.00001,warmup_epochs=15,decay_epochs=85,steps_per_epoch=len(ds),)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn)

history = model.fit(ds, validation_data=val_ds, callbacks=[display_cb], epochs=90)


Does this answer your question? Can't save custom subclassed model

Hi@Omar Bouaziz, If you're using a subclassed model in TensorFlow, saving the model for deployment can be a bit tricky, as the standard model.save() method won't work. However, there are still several approaches you can take to save your model:You can save only the weights of the model using model.save_weights(filepath). Later, you can recreate the model architecture and load the saved weights into it.You can save the model architecture as a JSON or YAML file and save the weights separately.Choose the approach that best fits your requirements and preferences
